# Python Glob Orignal Directories using Regex

Tags: python, regex, glob, pathlib

I have a bunch of directories that follow this naming convention:

```
foo
foo.v2
foo_v01
foo_v02
foo_v03
bar
bar.v3
bar_v01
bar_v02
```

I am looking for a regex expression to only glob original directories (foo and foo_v01; bar and bar_v01). I'm using the `Path.glob(pattern)` from `pathlib` to glob the files. I would like to glob the original directories specifically by the name, not by timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your examples (if it doesn't work for others, please add them to your question)

```
r'^(?!\w+_v0[2-9])(\w+)$'
```

Explanation:

`(\w+)` means that it should match any combination of letters, underscore, and numbers, one or more times.

`(?!\w+_v0[2-9])` means that if it matches any combination the same as above, followed by `_v0<any_number_from_2_to_9>` (versions above 1), it should discard the match.

Comment: `[\w\d]` = `\w`

Answer (score 0):

[Glob patterns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#module-glob) (which utilize [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) under the hood) are not [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) and are much more limited than regular expressions.

Here's an alternative approach, actually using regular expressions to perform the filtering:

```py
import os
import re

ROOT_DIR = "./dirs"
FILTER_RE = r"[._]v\d*[2-9]$"

filtered_dirs = [d for d in os.listdir(ROOT_DIR) if not re.search(FILTER_RE, d)]

print(sorted(filtered_dirs))
```

And here's the output:

```
$ ls dirs
bar  bar.v3  bar_v01  bar_v02  foo  foo.v2  foo_v01  foo_v02  foo_v03

$ python3 filter_dirs.py
['bar', 'bar_v01', 'foo', 'foo_v01']
```

Comment: `I am looking for a regex expression to only glob original directories (foo and foo_v01; bar and bar_v01)`, he does not want `foo_v02` and `foo_v03` to match